# How to check if, in a given list of objects, each different type of object is comparable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, types

As a means of defensive programming, I have implemented a fairly simple piece of code to check whether all of the elements (different types) of a given list passed to my function, are comparable with one another via the comparison operators (have one or all of the rich comparison methods implemented).

My take on this would be to iterate over the list and catalogue the available types along with single instances of each object in a dictionary and then run through the keys of the dictionary comparing each of the selected objects to one another to see if they return a Boolean value or raise a `TypeError`.

Below is an implementation of my idea:

```
test = [1, 2, 'str', 4.5, {'r':'d'}]

type_dict = {}
for elem in test:
    if not isinstance(elem, tuple(type_dict.keys())):
        type_dict[type(elem)] = elem
cmp = True
for obj1 in type_dict.keys():
    for obj2 in type_dict.keys():
        try:
            type_dict.get(obj1) > type_dict.get(obj2)
        except TypeError:
            cmp = False
            break
    if not cmp:
        break
if cmp:
    print('Objects in list are comparable.')
else:
    print('Objects in list are not comparable.')
```

Just out of curiosity is there a more concise way of doing this via pythons built-in's or libraries?

Comment: Can you clarify what your goal is? If you are looking for performance, surely just doing ``sorted(test)`` is faster to determine if items can be compared?

Comment: Mainly simplification and reduction of used code, but also different ways to reach the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do is to try and sort the list.

```
try:
    sorted(list_of_elements)
    print('Objects in list are comparable.')
except TypeError:
    print('Objects in list are not comparable.')
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding yyour question correctly but I think you could do something fairly simple like :

```
def check_type(test) :
  for i in test :
    if type(test[i])!=type(test[0]) :
      return False
  return True
```

Comment: This produces false negatives. Note how ``1.0 < 2`` is well-defined, yet ``type(1.0) == type(2)`` is false.

Comment: Also, this only compares the first element to the i-th element. It does not check any other pair of elements

Comment: And `test[i]` should be `i`